# Dealing with discontinuous phase issue in computing winding number numerically

Tags: computational-physics, topological-insulators, topological-phase

Consider a 1D SSH model with winding number given by
$$\nu = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\pi}^\pi d\phi,$$
where $d\phi$ is the change in phase of the eigenvectors between nearby $k$ points. The phase is given by
$$\phi = arctan(h_x/h_y),$$
with $h_x = v-w\cos(k), h_y = -w\cos(k)$ and $v,w$ are hopping parameters. We expect $\nu = 1$ when $|v| < |w|$ and $\nu=0$ otherwise. It is easy to show that this is true analytically. If we plot the phase numerically, we see that in the topological phase, the phase changes from $0$ to $2\pi$, whereas in the trivial phase, the phase changes from $0$ to some number smaller than $\pi$ and back to $0$.

However, when I try to use Python to evaluate it numerically the winding number of the topological phase, because the range of angle is between $[-\pi, \pi]$, there is a discontinuous jump in phase when it exceeds $\pi$. If I perform the naive finite difference to compute the change in phase, then both the topological and trivial phase will return winding number of 0. This is because the discontinuous jump in phase is $2\pi$, which exactly offsets the winding number. Anyone has encountered a similar issue before? If so, how should one deal with the discontinuous jump in phase in python/numpy?

I imagine the same issue will arise when computing other topological invariant quantities, such as Chern number.